How to Maintain UITableView Scroll Position When Loading More Data on Upward Scroll (Pagination)?
I'm implementing pagination for a UITableView in my iOS app. When the user scrolls upward to load more data (e.g., previous messages in a chat), I want to ensure that the table view maintains its current scroll position, so the user doesn't experience a "jump" after new data is loaded.
How can I ensure that the scroll position stays consistent after reloading the table view during upward scrolling and pagination? Is there a better way to handle this scenario?
private func setupViewModelObserver() {
    self.viewModel.apiResultChatList.bind(observer: { [unowned self] (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let data):
            self.hideTopLoader()
            self.remainingIterations = self.viewModel.latestRemainingIterations
            self.isProposalAcceptedByCretor = self.viewModel.isProposalAcceptedByCreator
            self.draftStatus = self.viewModel.draftStatus
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                if self.pageNumber == 1 {
                    // Initial load
                    self.scrollToBottom()
                    self.tblView.reloadData()
                } else {
                    // Save the current content offset and height
                       let previousContentHeight = self.tblView.contentSize.height
                       let previousOffset = self.tblView.contentOffset.y

                       // Reload the table view
                       self.tblView.reloadData()
                       self.tblView.layoutIfNeeded() // Ensure layout is updated before calculations

                       // Calculate the new content height
                       let newContentHeight = self.tblView.contentSize.height
                       let offsetDifference = newContentHeight - previousContentHeight

                       // Adjust content offset to maintain the current view position
                       self.tblView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: previousOffset + offsetDifference), animated: false)
                }
            self.setupAttachmentView() // Ensure this updates the attachment view after remainingIterations is updated
        case .failure(let error):
            Alert.shared.showSnackBar(error.errorDescription ?? "", isError: true)
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self.hideTopLoader()
        case .none: break
        }
    })

}
